# jquery datepicker's alywas return today's date in php $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datepicker

Note : I use the latest version of Codeigniter and Jquery in this project. Im a beginner in a web programming, please bear with me :D

This is my view/html code :

```
 Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"
 value="<?php echo isset($umat['tanggal_lahir'])?$umat['tanggal_lahir']:""?>"/>
```

This is my JS code for datepicker :

```
 $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
```

And this is a snippet my controllers/PHP code :

```
'tanggal_lahir' => $_POST['datepicker']
```

*(I dont know if this is related to my problem or not)I got a strange fact in this code, i dont use `$this->input->post` (CI built in function) because when i use it, the web will error because the `datepicker` have no value.*

Those code above always return today's date (it should return the user's selected date).

**What should i do so i can get the value from the datepicker and use it in php?**

Note : Some people said i should use AJAX, well im kinda of blind in AJAX. However i tried to use it, but its still not working for now. I dont include my AJAX code because im not sure its the only way to accomplish this, and one of my friend (which is a proffesional web developer) said that i DONT need to use AJAX to accomplish this.

This is the prove that my friend gave to me (**This is NOT in my project**, just a very simple example to show me that we can simply use $_POST) :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#txtdate").datepick();
    });
</script>
<form method="post">
Anda $_POST = <?php if (isset($_POST['txtdate'])) echo $_POST['txtdate'];?><br/>
<input type="text" name="txtdate" id="txtdate" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have tried this small program (the code above), and its working. **But, why the $_POST in here is working (returning selected date), but its not working (always returning today's date) in my project?**

Thanks for your time and sorry if i made some mistake or if this question is confusing you (English is not my first languange). Please feel free to ask something about this question if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

php is picky on conditional statements, try this:

```
Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"
 value="<?php echo (isset($umat['tanggal_lahir'])?$umat['tanggal_lahir']:"") ?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try your solution and i will let you know :D

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get it directly after it is set without sumbmiting the form and realod the page.. you have to use ajax becouse once php is loaded you can only use php with ajax on the same page..
i think i understand you correctly if you want to get je date directly after it is set without reloading the page

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can you kindly help me with the code?i tried to googling it, and implement the codes i got, but its still not working.